# Parsing an XML document from a decrypted string

Tags: xml, vb.net, encryption

I'm writing a Vb.Net application that reads an encrypted XML file from a PHP server.  I'm using the code snippets found here:

[PHP Encryption & VB.net Decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278974/php-encryption-vb-net-decryption)

specifically Richard Varno's answer and code.  I can compare the original XML file on the PHP server to the decrypted version on VB.Net and they are identical.

The problem is that when I load the decrypted version into an XML document in Vb.Net I just get an empty document.

If I load the unencrypted version from the PHP server it's fine.  I can't see any obvious difference between the two other than that one has been encrypted and then de-encrypted.  Both are strings, and both have been Gzipped so why would this not work ?

Here's my code to read in the unencrypted string:

```
Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(lookupUrl)

' Tell the server that we want it compressed
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
request.Timeout = 3000 ' Set 3 second timeout

' Parse the contents from the response to a stream object
stream = response.GetResponseStream()

' Create a reader for the stream object
Dim reader As New StreamReader(stream)

' Read from the stream object using the reader, put the encrypted contents in a string
Dim contents As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
' Put de-encrypted contents into another string
Dim decrypted As String = ""

' Create a new, empty XML document
Dim document As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
Console.WriteLine("Received: " & contents)

' De-encrypt the data from the response from the server
decrypted = DecryptRJ256(Globals.sKy, Globals.sIV, contents)
Console.WriteLine("Decrypted: " & decrypted)

' Load the contents into the XML document
document.LoadXml(contents)

Dim nodes As XmlNodeList =     document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//results/Node1")
```

Now the above works but if I replace

```
document.LoadXml(contents)
```

with:

```
document.LoadXml(decrypted)
```

my XML document is empty.

Comment: Based on this info, I would have to guess your xml is not actually encrypted. What is the output where you write `"Received: " & contents)`?

Comment: It is encrypted.  I can't post it all as it's too long for a comment but it starts : l4QiwAAs9m/ZEetl4fsXTvBC2Y/PFtI4WEteGADcHlGHcqlr5C5N5AuVAv97bWvAqVAvLBWVDMXg6dDMNJAdDZg95soIZ/hAVkYGV4IvQHZo2emg+TVz160p6ZiW26mL3uvZOTuT722CbECIm3y4u/ and decrypting it gives me the XML that the server generated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `DecryptRJ256`. It must mutate the third parameter (`contents`), that is the only way `LoadXml(contents)` would work. What is the return value from `DecryptRJ256` ?

Comment: It is exactly as I would expect e.g.
 <xml>
    <results>
        <Aircraft>
            <hex>43E907</hex>
            <lat>51.7536</lat>
            <lon>-1.3534</lon>
            <spd>262</spd>
 
 etc ...

Comment: ok, then the only advice I have left is to trap and inspect exceptions. If the document is empty it is most likely throwing an exception.

Comment: I do that already - I just didn't show them to aid ease of reading.  No exceptions are thrown.  I've checked the line endings in a text editor and they appear to be the the same so I'm stumped !

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the decryption function was padding out the end of the decrypted string with null characters.  When viewed as hex these appeared as 00 but the output I had via console.writeline wasn't showing these at all.

Null characters are not valid XML which is why I wasn't getting any output.

The solution was to write a function which walked the decrypted string and stripped these using (in my case on .Net 4.0) the XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(ch) function.

Once stripped of null characters I got the expected decrypted output.

Comment: invalid padding should have thrown an exception

Comment: You're right - it did but my code wasn't trapping it for some reason but it was appearing in Events tab of the Diagnostic tools.  I had the Memory Usage tab selected so didn't see them. Doh !